# Cargar datos en mi select numero dos - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

tengo un select que me carga sin problemas la información de mi api pero necesito hacer lo mismo con mi otro select que viene con `react-windowed-select` pero no lo he logrado ya que este tipo de select me permite cargar grandes listas y se renderiza mejor en cambio el select normal de react al traer grandes listas se pone muy lento.

select normal funcionando:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-jasper-6j6rvl?file=/src/App.js:0-1019

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [t4t, setUniversidad] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const getcountry2 = async () => {
        const req = await fetch(
          `https://aliraweb.com/apiAlira2/cargar_empleados/nombre_trabajador.php?id_empresa_usuario=30`
        );
        const getres2 = await req.json();
        setUniversidad(await getres2);
      };
      getcountry2();
    }, 2000);
    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        // name="t4"
        className="form-select"
      >
        <option>--Seleccione --</option>
        {t4t.map((getcon2) => (
          <option key={getcon2.id} value={getcon2.name}>
            {" "}
            {getcon2.documento} - {getcon2.name}{" "}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <br />
      {/*  <input type="text"  value={getcon2.documento} />*/}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//este es mi otro select "react-windowed-select" en la cual quiero que haga lo mismo que el anterior ósea que cargue la base de datos desde la api **pero no lo he logrado hacerlo**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-darkness-5844h6?file=/src/App.jsx:0-790

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import WindowedSelect from "react-windowed-select";

function App() {
  const [t4t, setUniversidad] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const getcountry2 = async () => {
        const req = await fetch(
          `https://aliraweb.com/apiAlira2/cargar_empleados/nombre_trabajador.php?id_empresa_usuario=30`
        );
        const getres2 = await req.json();
        setUniversidad(await getres2);
      };
      getcountry2();
    }, 2000);
    return () => setInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  //opciones
  const options = [];

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <br />

        <WindowedSelect options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import WindowedSelect from "react-windowed-select";

function App() {
  const [t4t, setUniversidad] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const req = await fetch(
        `https://witalenco.com.co/apiWittytalent/dyc/titulos/carreras.php`
      );
      const getres2 = await req.json();
      console.log({ getres2 });
      setUniversidad(await getres2);
    })();
  }, []);

  // Here is the transformation
  const options = t4t.map((item) => ({
    label: item.carrera,
    value: item.id_titulos
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <br />

        <WindowedSelect options={options} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta a tu propia pregunta? Si lo es, debes argumentar (lo mínimo necesario) el porqué esto resuelve el problema, puedes leer [answer]. Si no lo es, entonces debes editar la pregunta y añadir cualquier información adicional. El formato de [es.so] es muy simple: **una** pregunta en el área de la pregunta y una o más respuestas en el área de respuestas. Aquí no se mejan las publicaciones como *hilos* de las redes antisociales.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponer que el codigo que pusiste como respuesta es un complemento del codigo que pusiste inicialmente voy a tomar esa respuesta como el codigo que tienes actualmente, el cual te podria recomendar las siguientes mejoras para que sea mas limpio:
No utilizar `async` `await` para hacer el fetch, si no un `then()`

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`https://witalenco.com.co/apiWittytalent/dyc/titulos/carreras.php`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setUniversidad(data)
}, []);
```

Se ve mas limpio y facil de entender. 
Sin embargo si quieres utilizar `async` `await` veo que al principio antes de la palabra `async` tienes un parentesis de mas, por otro lado no deberias usar await al actualizar el estado `setUniversidad()` 
Otra recomendacion, si creas un estado colocales el mismo nombre, al escalar la aplicacion se hara mas facil entender en este caso `[univerdad, setUniversidad] = useState([])` quizas con los cambios que te mencione, las opciones aparezcan