# Como utilizar select options con peticiones fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

intento realizar un select de options las cuales cada uno mostrarian informacion relacionada con noticias de cada pais escogido pero no logro relacionar cada option con cada funcion de cada pais, tengo tres paises cada uno con funcion fetch realizada y puesta en un useEffect, no si se pueda utilizar un solo useState, la finalidad es que al escoger un pais se actualice el codigo que esta dentro del Link.

````
const [news, setNews] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    loadNews().then((data) => setNews(data.results))
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    spainNews().then((data) => setNews(data.results))
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    colombiaNews().then((data) => setNews(data.results))
},[])

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
  
return (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <div>
            <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                <option>Select</option>
                <option value='usa'>Usa</option>
                <option value='spain'>Spain</option>
                <option value='colombia'>Colombia</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 md:mx-5 gap-5 mx-3'>
            {news.map((lea) => (
                <Link to={`/details/${lea.article_id}`} className='mt-10 shadow-2xl shadow-neutral-500'>
                    <div key={lea.article_id}>
                        <div className='font-light text-zinc-950 text-lg mx-2'>
                            {lea.title}
                        </div>
                        <div className='mt-4'>
                            <img className='md:w-[500px] w-90 h-60' src={lea.image_url}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link> 
            ))}
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </div>
  ) ```
````

Comment: Esta respuesta puede ser de ayuda [react select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/601262/101408)

Comment: Hola, tengo 3 dudas primero la información que tienes en los fetch de cada pías es igual para todas?  segundo podrías decir que estructura tiene la respuesta de los fetch, actualiza el post y tercero podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que quieres.